# Error en importacion de Datos SSIS

Tags: ssis

Hola muy buenas noches chicos.

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto ETL. Voy bastante avanzado, pero escribo por que tengo un inconveniente que me quiebra la cabeza.

Tengo una Tarea que incluye la carga de un archivo .csv y luego la almacena en una tabla dentro del servidor SQL.

El punto es que la rutina en ambiente en desarrollo funciona correctamente, pero cuando lo paso a producción la rutina se quiebra informando :

"[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: Código de error SSIS DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED. Error del método ProcessInput en el componente "Almacenar información en Snapshot" (2). Código de error: 0xC0209029 mientras se procesaba la entrada "Entrada de destino de OLE DB" (15). El componente identificado devolvió un error del método ProcessInput. El error es específico del componente, pero es grave y detendrá la ejecución de la tarea Flujo de datos. Puede que haya otros mensajes de error expuestos anteriores a éste con más información sobre el error."

La estructura de tablas en ambos ambientes son idénticos.

salvo que las versiones de los servidores SQL son distintas:

Versión del servidor en ambiente de producción:

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5538.0 (X64)   Apr  3 2015 14:50:02   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporación  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: ) (VM)

Idioma:

us_english

Versión del servidor en ambiente de prueba:

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-GDR) (KB4019088) - 13.0.1742.0 (X64)   Jul  5 2017 23:41:17   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3  (Build 19042: )

Idioma :

Español

Dentro de integration services habilite y deshabilite las opciones :

RunInOptimizedMode

Run64BitRuntime.

Quizás mi inconveniente se deba a que la configuración del idioma por los puntos y comas, ya que en ambos servidores son distintos.

PD: No se me permite alterar atributos en el servidor de producción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Asegúrate de que los campos en origen y destino tienen el mismo tipo de datos. Si eso es así, lo más probable es que tengas problemas con la conversión implícita que pueda estar haciendo el proceso en campos de fecha debido al idioma.

Comment: Pero recuerda que el idioma no lo define la base de datos, lo define el usuario a la cual se conecta.

Comment: Gracias. me he dado cuenta que el problema es otro y se debe a la memoria máxima del servidor de producción.  El servidor de producción tiene un máximo de 46000 mb y el archivo .csv contiene campos con largos mayores a 400 caracteres. Asi que me imagino que por ahí va el tema.

Comment: Bien, intente cambiando la capacidad máxima a lo mismo que tiene el servidor de desarrollo pero sigue fallando. las asignaciones de los tipos de datos en SSIS y SQL server son idénticas. No se que puede ocurrir.